# Code Injection works in C# too!

Tags: code-golf, c#, programming-puzzle

Given the following C# program outputting `False`, inject a 'malicious' line of code such that the program outputs `True`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.Write("False");
        ;
    }
}
```

Your answer should consist of a string that replaces the second semicolon, and causes the program to output `True`, the whole `True` and nothing but `True` (not even a newline). It must do this if stdout is printed to the console, and if stdout is redirected to a file.

The shortest answer wins.

Comment: What's your objective winning criterion?

Comment: @JB Do puzzles need a winning criterion? Will edit.

Comment: I'm mostly reacting to the code-golf remark, but the point stands: which will be the accepted answer?

Comment: @JB Shortest answer is best answer.

Comment: Well it *is* code-golf, then, isn't it?

Comment: @JB That's kind of a secondary goal, but I suppose I should add the tag.

Comment: I've added an additional criterion and changed it to `Write` instead of `WriteLine`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### 52 characters

```
}static Program(){System.Console.Write(0<1);for(;;);
```

so the whole thing becomes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.Write( "False" );
    }
    static Program()
    {
        System.Console.Write( 0 < 1 ); 
        for ( ; ; ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for editing the question in the middle of your answer. Newlines are no longer allowed, you'll have to use `Write`.

Comment: Ok, I've changed `WriteLine` to `Write`

Comment: You could probably save some bytes by replacing your exit with `for(;;);`, nothing I've seen requires that the program terminates...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, that meets the requirements as specified.

Comment: `}static Program(){System.Console.Write(0<1);for(;;);` could always become `}static Program(){for(System.Console.Write(0<1);;);`

Answer (score 7):

C#, 51 characters

```
Console.Write("\b\b\b\b\b");Console.Write("True ");
```

Will only work on standard output

Comment: First thing I tried, unfortunately it won't work because of the initial `WriteLine`.

Comment: Now it is `Write` :/ I don't get how we would manage to solve this if it keeps changing...

Comment: @Vereos I wanted to remove the ambiguity of 'newline or no newline'.

Comment: You don't need 2 instances of `Console.Write`, and you could use `\r` instead of 5 `\b`s. `Console.Write("\rTrue ");`

Comment: I don't think it meets the criteria.  It actually outputs False first, which is then overwtitten by True later.

Answer (score 2):

You can generalize RamonBoza's answer to still work if stdout is redirected to a file.

Assuming the program runs under Mono on Linux, with the assembly `Mono.Posix.dll` loaded:

```
if(Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.isatty(1))
{
    Console.Write("\rTrue ");
}
else
{
    // Truncate the output file first
    Console.OpenStandardOutput().SetLength(0);
    Console.Write("True");
}
```

I doubt this works on Windows, but there's probably an equivalent to `isatty()`.

Answer (score 1):

**83... WIP**

I was hoping this'd work, but apparently "False" isn't being interned as I'd hoped in my compiler

```
//}unsafe static Program(){fixed(char*f="False"){*(long*)f=0x65007500720054;*(f+4)=' ';}
}unsafe static Program(){fixed(char*f="False")for(int i=5;i-->0;)*(f+i)="True "[i];
```

ungolfed

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("False");
    }

    unsafe static Program()
    {
        fixed (char* f = "False") for (int i = 5; i-- > 0; ) *(f + i) = "True "[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.Write("False");

        System.Console.Clear(); System.Console.Write("True");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if stdout is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is accepted.
The question doesn't say anything about compiler options so I assume I can change the entry point of the app.
55 characters ,3 more than the accepted answer

```
}class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write(1>0);}
```

Full

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.Write("False");
    }
    class P
    {
        static void Main() { System.Console.Write(1 > 0); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community!

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Thanks. This is a fantastic site!!!